# Calculator that takes an operator as user input

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a calculator that takes user input. I want this input to include not just the numbers, but the operator as well (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). I created a method that works with a given parameter. Here is my code:

```
def calculator(x, y, z)
    if y == '+'
        ans = x + z
    elsif y == '-'
        ans = x - z
    elsif y == '*'
        ans = x * z
    elsif y == '/'
        ans = x / z
    end
    p ans
end

calculator(3, '+', 5)
calculator(4, '-', 2)
calculator(3, '*', 10)
calculator(21, '/', 7)

puts "Please enter your calculation"
user_calc = gets.chomp

user_calc.chars
user_calc[0].to_i
user_calc[4].to_i
calculator(user_calc[0], user_calc[2], user_calc[4])
```

The program assumes index `0` to be the first integer, index `2` the operator, and index `4` the second integer.

When I input `3 + 5`, the output is `35` instead of `8`. Any other operation (`-`, `*`, `/`) returns `nil`. When I try to use user input, I run into an error. I think it treats everything in the array as a string. The given parameters work as intended. But I cannot quite nail down the user input.

I'm wondering how I would go about fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user_calc[0].to_i` *returns* a number as its result; it doesn't *turn* `user_calc[0]` into one. So

```
calculator(user_calc[0], user_calc[2], user_calc[4])
```

is doing

```
calculator("3", "+", "5")
```

and `"3" + "5"` is `"35"`.

The correct way would be to write

```
calculator(user_calc[0].to_i, user_calc[2], user_calc[4].to_i)
```

or

```
arg1 = user_calc[0].to_i
arg2 = user_calc[4].to_i
calculator(arg1, user_calc[2], arg2)
```

Comment: Thank you, Amadan. I see why I wasn't getting the correct returns now. 
I've been thinking a little more, and I had an additional question that I've been trying to solve. Is there a way to treat each input (x, y, z) as it's own index? 

Right now, even if I 

user_calc.split(' ')
, each character is treated as it's own index. So, for example, 5 + 95 would return 5 + 9 instead. I'm wondering how I could split up user_calc differently. 

In other words, how would I get a return of 100 for 5 + 95 instead of a return of 14.

Comment: As Keith said, regular expressions. `_, arg1, op, arg2 = *"5 + 95".match(/(\d+)\s*([-+*\/])\s*(\d+)/)` will extract two integer arguments (as strings, you still need to `to_i` them) and an operator between them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the need for `to_i` stated in another answer, `user_calc[n]` is getting the nth character.  This would not handle characters < 0 or > 9.  Instead you could use regular expressions to extract the terms (which by the way should be better named, e.g. `x`, `operator`, `y`).

You can go to http://rubular.com/ for a great regular expression tester.

In addition, there are ways to simplify your `calculator` method.  For example, you could use `case`:

```
def calculator(x, y, z)
    case y
    when '+'
        ans = x + z
    when '-'
        ans = x - z
    when '*'
        ans = x * z
    when '/'
        ans = x / z
    end
    p ans
end
```

...and further, by moving the assignment outside the case statement:

```
def calculator(x, y, z)
    x = x.to_i; z = z.to_i
    ans = case y
    when '+'
        x + z
    when '-'
        x - z
    when '*'
        x * z
    when '/'
        x / z
    end
    p ans
end
```

There is also `send`, but with that it is even more important to validate the operator to ensure it was one of those you can handle.